iframe postMessage alternatives existing? Eg. bind functions to iframe?
Context
Accessing a document in an iframe from a parent window and accessing a parent window's document from an iframe is possible without CORS or when each iframe's document's origin is the same as the other iframe's document's origin when the iframe is not sandboxed.
A document in a sandboxed iframe without allow-same-origin is accessible like an access forbidding CORS policy in the response header which the document came with: not.
postMessage to an other (iframe) window which if that listens to messages allows communication between source and destination window.
Problem
postMessage is text-based, functions and references to them are not supported by the structured clone algorithm.
Question
Which way exists or is planned or is conferred about which allows to assign functions to another window (in particular to an iframe's from parent window) to be callable from that other window?
Further info
This would be like an API which is specified from a source window for another window and which could be a JavaScript object whose keys' value is a function.

Nothing exists like what you're asking for in the browser. But you could build it yourself with a little JS.
Step one would be to put all your RPC functions on to an object, then you can write a few lines to receive a message and call your function.
window.addEventListener(
  "message",
  ({ data }) => {
    const [func, ...args] = data
    RPC[func](...args)
  },
  false
)

Then in the parent page you would have a function to make the call.
const setupRPC = (target) => (func) => (...args) {
  target.postMessage([func, ...args], '*')
}

Now to create an RPC call you would first create a factory function.
const myiframe = document.getElementById('myiframe')
const createIframeFunc = setupRPC(myiframe)

Then we can use this to create RPC functions.
const myFunc = createIframeFunc('myFunc')

Then we just call it.
myFunc({ a: ['b', 'c'] } )

postMessage will serialise and deserialise your data for you.
